# What is the "Fields view get" option in the Odoo 11 developer menu?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am trying to debug a module by using the developer mode and the menu that can be opened using the bug symbol. There is a menu item "Edit form view" which is quite handy if you want to look at the source code of forms. There is also the menu item "Fields view get" which shows the same form in a slightly different way.

I do not understand where the extra items come from. There are several additional attributes in the field definition and often there is the item modifiers="{...}".

Where do these additional attributes come from?

Example code from a form that defines a partner:

**fields view get**

```
<form string="Partner" modifiers="{}">
<sheet modifiers="{}">
    <div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box" modifiers="{}">
        <button class="oe_stat_button o_res_partner_tip_opp" type="action" attrs="{'invisible': [('customer', '=', False)]}" name="273" icon="fa-star" context="{'search_default_partner_id': active_id}" modifiers="{'invisible':[['customer','=',false]]}" options="{}">
            <field string="Verkaufschancen" name="opportunity_count" widget="statinfo" modifiers="{'readonly':true}"/>
        </button>
```

**edit form view**

```
<form string="Partners">
            <sheet>
                <div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box">
                    <button name="toggle_active" type="object" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-archive">
                        <field name="active" widget="boolean_button" options="{&quot;terminology&quot;: &quot;archive&quot;}"/>
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About fields view_get**

Every model of Odoo has a `fields_view_get` method which you can overwrite. this method is executed once the XML code of the view is loaded and before being rendered to HTML. This means that you can do some dynamic modifications in the views. Look for `def fields_view_get` in the Odoo modules, you will find a lot of cases. An example:

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False,
                    submenu=False):
    result = super(AccountMoveLine, self).fields_view_get(view_id,
                                                          view_type,
                                                          toolbar=toolbar,
                                                          submenu=submenu)

    doc = etree.XML(result['arch'])
    if view_type == 'tree' and self._module == 'account_payment_order':
        if not doc.xpath("//field[@name='balance']"):
            for placeholder in doc.xpath(
                    "//field[@name='amount_currency']"):
                elem = etree.Element(
                    'field', {
                        'name': 'balance',
                        'readonly': 'True'
                    })
                orm.setup_modifiers(elem)
                placeholder.addprevious(elem)
        if not doc.xpath("//field[@name='amount_residual_currency']"):
            for placeholder in doc.xpath(
                    "//field[@name='amount_currency']"):
                elem = etree.Element(
                    'field', {
                        'name': 'amount_residual_currency',
                        'readonly': 'True'
                    })
                orm.setup_modifiers(elem)
                placeholder.addnext(elem)
        if not doc.xpath("//field[@name='amount_residual']"):
            for placeholder in doc.xpath(
                    "//field[@name='amount_currency']"):
                elem = etree.Element(
                    'field', {
                        'name': 'amount_residual',
                        'readonly': 'True'
                    })
                orm.setup_modifiers(elem)
                placeholder.addnext(elem)
        # Remove credit and debit data - which is irrelevant in this case
        for elem in doc.xpath("//field[@name='debit']"):
            doc.remove(elem)
        for elem in doc.xpath("//field[@name='credit']"):
            doc.remove(elem)
        result['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return result
```

**About modifiers**

Modifiers are intended to replace `attrs` and other attributes (`readonly`, `required`, `invisible`). For the moment, they exist along side of those attributes. The reason to introduce them is to streamline things for the new web client so it can only look at one place. Also evaluation of `modifiers` will happen server-side, relinquishing the need for a python (-like) interpreter client-side. Finally, modifiers concrete syntax will be **json** (information taken from https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/168924).

**Conclusion**

In summary, answering your question, what you see in **Edit form view** is the pure XML code of the view, the same you will see in the XML files of the Odoo modules, whereas **Fields view get** is that code after being loaded and transformed to be rendered in client side.

Comment: Thank you, that sheds some light on it. Does it mean that every word "modifier" I see in the "fields view get" display can only be reached by overriding the function and every extra attribute I discover is originated in another xml view (which I have to find and inherit to override the attributes)?

Comment: @thopy exactly. You can easily find the added modifications in the *Edit X View* (where X is form, tree, kanban...), in the *Inherited views* tab. But each one of these views has its own *Inherited views* tab with its own modifications, so, depending on the view, seeing all modifications could take a few time. By the way, if this answer was helpful for you, please check it as useful or the correct answer. Thank you!