# Domain depending on a field in odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo

I have this model and method in odoo

```
class stock_transfer_details_items(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'stock.transfer_details_items'

    lot_id = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', 'Lot/Serial Number')
    q_auth = fields.Boolean(related='lot_id.q_auth', string="Quality Auth.")
    needs_auth = fields.Boolean(related='product_id.needs_quality_auth')

    @api.onchange("needs_auth")
    def _onchange_NQA_domain(self):
     domain = {'domain': {'lot_id': [('product_id', '=', rec.product_id.id)]}}
     if rec.needs_auth:
         domain = {'domain': {'lot_id': [('q_auth', '!=', False), ('product_id', '=', rec.product_id.id)]}}
     return domain
```

All this code is working ok. My problem is that I need to apply this domain when the wizard opens. `@api.depends` means that the value changes depending on the value of `needs_auth` but it actually don't work if I don't interact with the checkbox of `needs_auth`. I want to apply the domain when the view is open and not interact with the needs_auth field, because the user will not be allow to interact.

Comment: All you have to do is, You have to set this same domain in XML side where you have defined the action of the wizard, and it will work when you will open the wizard, if statement is applicable there as well

Comment: Hi Sidharth. I don't know how to make it work the conditional in XML, that's why I was doing it in Python. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your problem is to use `fields_view_get`.
It was already mentioned before here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825093/9796551

```py
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(stock_transfer_details_items,self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id,
                                                 view_type=view_type,
                                                 toolbar=toolbar,
                                                 submenu=submenu)
    if view_type == 'form':
        domain = "["
        # Your condition...
        domain += "]"
        res['fields']['lot_id']['domain'] = domain
    return res
```